# How to use UNION_DISTINCT() or INTERSECTION() after deprecation of NEIGHBORS()

Tags: arangodb

I am new to ArangoDB and am trying to reproduce the results of https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/28b266f143232beb17e5c35cd545d4f3909a1815/3.0/cookbook/graph-example-actors-and-movies.md.

It turns out that functions like NEIGHBORS() are deprecated in 3.0. There is a migration guide https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/28b266f143232beb17e5c35cd545d4f3909a1815/3.0/cookbook/aql-migrating-edge-functions-to3.md with which I manage to get

```
db._query("RETURN NEIGHBORS(movies, actsIn, 'TheMatrix', 'any')").toArray();
```

to work again as

```
db._query("FOR x IN ANY 'movies/TheMatrix' actsIn RETURN x._key").toArray();
```

However, I am at a loss how to use `UNION_DISTINCT` or `INTERSECTION` as the `RETURN` statement sits inside the loop, not outside. Also, I cannot seem to find any documentation on given functions anywhere?

For instance: "All actors who acted in both "movie1" AND "movie2" ?" would have been queried as

```
db._query("RETURN INTERSECTION(NEIGHBORS(movies, actsIn, 'TheDevilsAdvocate', 'any'), NEIGHBORS(movies, actsIn, 'TheMatrix', 'any'))").toArray();
```

which reads naturally coming from an sql background. But how would one go about this using above-mentioned for loop?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the documentation for these functions here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/array/

Your AQL for the cookbook-example should look like these:

#### UNION_DISTINCT

`db._query("FOR x IN UNION_DISTINCT ((FOR y IN ANY 'movies/TheMatrix' actsIn RETURN y), (FOR y IN ANY 'movies/TheDevilsAdvocate' actsIn RETURN y)) RETURN x._id").toArray()`

#### INTERSECTION

`db._query("FOR x IN INTERSECTION ((FOR y IN ANY 'movies/TheMatrix' actsIn RETURN y), (FOR y IN ANY 'movies/TheDevilsAdvocate' actsIn RETURN y)) RETURN x._id").toArray()`

Comment: This indeed solves my problem. I was confused because I had read somewhere in the docs that only a single mention of `RETURN` is allowed per query.

Comment: Updated examples: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/examples-and-query-patterns/actors-and-movies-dataset-queries/